# CDT Include Discovery for custom toolchain

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, include, eclipse-cdt, toolchain

I have written a custom CDT toolchain that supports a gcc-based toolchain (e.g. sparc-elf-gcc).

Everything is working as far as compiling goes, but when I include a standard library (e.g. stdio.h) the UI indicates an unresolved inclusion.

I can manually add include paths under Paths and Symbols in the C/C++ General section of the project's properties. This works, but it would be nice if it worked in the same way as standard CDT works with MinGW - it just knows where to find MinGW includes.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 4):

CDT 8.1 (Eclipse Juno) offers a new API to contribute built-in include paths to a project programmatically.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn81#Scanner_Discovery

The API uses the extension point

```
org.eclipse.cdt.core.LanguageSettingsProvider
```

and is centered on the interface

```
org.eclipse.cdt.core.language.settings.providers.ILanguageSettingsProvider
```

This improves the API used by previous CDT versions (`IExternalScannerInfoProvider`, `IScannerInfoCollector`, etc).